# How do you secure/filter an HTML form submit with input file?

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a form with 2 inputs:

1. The file taken from the mobile phone's camera with input type="file"
2. A shortcode (a 6-character one-time, expiring password)

The requirements are 1) to validate that the shortcode is valid and 2) if it is, continue to receive the file.

Currently, in my implementation, if the short code is not valid, the server receives the file anyway, encodes it to base64, return it back to the client as a hidden form field, adds an error message.

I do not want to temporarily save the file on the server because it is not (yet) authorised. I encode the file to base64 for UX so that the user does not have to repeat the process of taking another picture again. He/She only needs to retype the short code (hopefully the correct one this time). Also, [some version of Safari on iOS crashes because the huge base64 input hidden text](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84168).

QUESTIONS: What are better alternatives such that:

1. I do not have to receive the image input (for security reasons and to save on bandwidth) if the shortcode is not valid?
2. The user does not have to recapture the image if the shortcode is not valid?

Comment: What is you question?

Answer (score 1):

Save the image on your server giving it an id, just send the id back to the user in a hidden field. Instead of sending the whole image back and forth between server and client, the server can hold on to the image and just give the client something to refer back to it later.

Things to note here:

- the id needs to be completely random and unguessable, otherwise the client could possibly trick the server into using an image of another user
- alternatively, if you can associate the upload with the user somehow that'll work as well (session data etc.)
- since the user may abandon the process at any point, your server may now have an image on disk which will never be used by anyone; you'll need to set up some sort of garbage collection which will remove any abandoned uploaded files periodically

Comment: IMO, if I accept the image without validating the short code, it is too optimistic that the user simply made a typo. This is a vulnerability that a hacker can exploit if he/she is able to effectively upload an unauthorised file. And between the time of upload and the routine garbage collection schedule, there is a window that can be exploited to activate the 'image' uploaded. Also, even for a simple attack to overload the disk by some robot will become possible in this case.

Comment: Even without temporary storage, a DoS attack could easily achieve the same thing. You'll probably also want to add a quota then, basically triggering garbage collection of the oldest files when reaching a certain threshold of disk capacity. Beyond this there should be no *vulnerability* if you're handling uploaded files correctly: never store them in a publicly accessible folder, and most certainly not under the user provided name (e.g. save `foo.php` to `public_html/uploads`).

Comment: Can you please expound that a "DoS attack could easily achieve the same thing"? Because I do not think it's the same. In my current implementation, a DoS attack can flood my bandwidth because of the form input file images but at least it will not overload my disk space. And even with the quota to trigger garbage collection, a person who simply did a typo can potentially lose his temporarily uploaded image.

Comment: If a DDoS is uploading many large files to your server, and the server saves it even just temporarily (during the current request), with enough uploads this can potentially fill your disk as well and/or grind it to a halt. This shouldn't really be your primary design decision, DoSes should be mitigated by appropriate mechanisms (`fail2ban` and things on that level), not primarily by your application design. *If* you ever get so much uploads that this becomes a real issue, you probably have bigger fish to fry anyway.

Comment: You gotta pick one solution: save the image or not save the image. If you're not going to save the image, either do an AJAX request for the confirmation code before the upload, as suggested by Oooogi, or you'll have to send the image back and forth between server and client (which you also don't really want and which is arguably the worst UX). You'll have to make *some* tradeoff.

Comment: But that's why I want to improve my current implementation such that in one HTTP request/transaction, the server would be accept the file if and only if the shortcode is valid. I know I can work my way around this but I'm simply taking my chances that some simple solution exists.

Comment: Thanks, @deceze. Please do not get me wrong. I do appreciate your (and Oog's) suggestions. I'm simply crossing my fingers and trying my luck that I do not have to do tradeoffs. And while hoping that somebody will suggest a simple and elegant solution, it might also well be that it will be proven that it cannot be done (without tradeoffs).

Comment: An HTTP request is one self-contained blob, there's exactly one request which contains both the code and the file. The server needs to receive the entire request and then decide how to handle it. You can't have your cake and eat it too. If you're going to send only one request, you can do it as you are now or you can do what I suggest. The alternative is to split it up into two separate requests, which is Oooogi's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you send the file anyway to the server if the password is not correct?

You could make a javascript ajax call to the server with the password to check if the password is valid. If it is valid then the callback from the ajax call can submit the form holding the input type="file".

Uploading a file of an unauthorized user is potentially dangerous - it's a waste of bandwidth at least.

**ADDED**

It goes without saying that you have to validate everything on the server side and not only on the client side.

A. You can include the password again in the form that sends the file.

B. Your ajax request can make the server side open a session cookie and 
remember you as validated (as long as the session is open). Then, when you submit the form with the file the server side validation would just have to check your session.

Comment: AJAX is indeed a solution but I do not want it if there should be other simpler alternatives that does not require it. Also, your suggestion, as to how I understand it is vulnerable to hacking because the second form submit called after the callback can be easily hi-jacked.

Comment: Hi @Dynameyes. I don't agree on both occasions. The non-ajax way requires you to waste bandwidth, cpu and disk space for files (not only images, because someone can just use it RESTfully to send you a file) which might not be associated with any user at the end. And for the second part - you could of course add a token received by the server or just send the password along with the file... there can be NO hijacking or hacking because the validation occurs on the server side (and not just by html/js)

Comment: Hi @Oooogi , sure your suggestion could work but I find it (IMO) complicated for a simple request. I am looking for a more elegant solution. Say, if I could use the HTTP header for the shortcode (i.e. if the header is read/processed prior to receiving the HTTP body or content)? Or issue a 403 but somehow for the client to recover gracefully without losing the input file perhaps.